# While in a function decorated transactional, if other functions are called that do stuff to db entities, is the whole operation transactional?

Tags: google-app-engine

For example:

```py
    def baz(self, id):
        return SomeModel.get_by_id(id)

    def boo(self, bar):
        # Do something to bar
        bar.put()

    @ndb.transactional()
    def foo(self, id):
        bar = self.baz(id)
        self.boo(bar)
```

Is an invocation of `foo` safely transactional? If not, why not?

Answer (score -1):

I've no idea why you would think calling out to another function would not be transactional. Of course, it will be: the API doesn't know or care where your calls are coming from, it just knows when you enter a transactional lock and when you later leave it.